# Rule to "Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts" returns unexpected results

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I have created a new individual rule, "Test Rule" where the only field (criteria) selected is "Email." I have assigned a weight of 10 to the email field and a total value for the rule also at 10. [image: Find and Merge Rule Screen]

My expectation is that only those contacts with the **same** email address would be returned after the search.

However, after running the rule, several contacts are identified as duplicates but they do not share the same email address. [image] I have highlighted those "duplicates" with different emails in red. Note that these red contacts have both different names and different emails, so I would not expect them to be included in a search where the only criteria is matching email.

I have also highlighted contacts with the same email, but different names in green. The contacts in green are what I would expect, same email, but different names.

Considering my rule is based on email only, why are contacts with different emails being returned as duplicates?

Note: This issue occurs with multiple rules used. The rule included here was created specifically to explain this issue and submit this question.

Thank you.

Comment: and have you ruled out possibility that those 'odd' results had more than one email on their record, and while your 'list' shows perhaps their primary email, they have another non-primary email that does match?

Comment: I had not ruled that out. Thank you. Looking at the individual records, rather than the search results or merge page, I see that indeed the returned contacts do share an email. I will close this. Thank you @petednz-fuzion

Answer (score 5):

The results of the search lists the "primary" email associated with the contact record. While the primary email presented in the search may not match, viewing the individual contact details--and all emails associated with a contact record--reveals that a duplicate email is indeed listed.